# How can I develop Safari App Extension without macOS app?

Tags: xcode, safari, safari-extension, mac-app-store, safari-app-extension

I've just developed a brand new Safari App Extension. I do not have any mac os app to share through the mac app store, only my extension THAT IS my product.

It seems ([from that Apple page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions)) that I must create a dummy mac os app to share my extension through mac app store. Am I right ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I managed to distribute my Safari Extension through the Mac App Store. 
The thing you have to keep in mind is the fact that you have to build a minimal single-window macos app which explain (like a tutorial) how to activate your extension in Safari.

What a mess ...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you seem to be correct. I'm in the same situation... I don't even want to sell or distribute the extension but just use it for myself.

Comment: If you do not want to distribute the extension, you can simply make it from Xcode (Product --> Archive. Click on 'Distribute App' button and chose 'Development' method). 
This will export the extension in a macOS app format. 
Then, you just have to run it and your extension will appear in Safari.